# PHP sdk to get user's country

Tags: php, facebook-php-sdk, locale

In facebook's php sdk, a LOCALE is returned in an array ( like en_GB ). So, how to use the LOCALE to get the country of the user, i.e., United Kingdom in this case...? I did a google search about that but could not find it...Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not facebook to get the country of the user...its complicated using facebook. I use the I.P. to determine the country of the user using php. Do a Google search of that to get a detailed description.

Answer (score 0):

[Locale](http://php.net/manual/en/class.locale.php), from the [Internationalization extension](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.intl.php), should help with that.

Anthony.